# unable to make a swipeAction in my scroll view in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swipe-gesture

I've got this piece of code below with a textfield, but the issue is when I try to add a swipeAction to enable the users to delete items on every row as needed, it doesnt work. Does anyone know a walkaround to make the swipeAction work. I really appreciate in advance. I am pretty sure it is possible to add a swipeAction to each row but not sure how

```
import SwiftUI


struct TableItems: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = [Item(id: UUID(), name: "", quantity: "", price: "", complete: "", shopName: "", isComplete: false)]
    @State private var item: Item = Item(id: UUID(), name: "", quantity: "", price: "", complete: "", shopName: "", isComplete: false)

    @EnvironmentObject var tableModel: TableModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // Add your camera button action here
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.cartvoltDarkBlue)
                

                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    hideKeyboard()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.cartvoltDarkBlue)
                
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.addRow()
                    // Add your to do checklist button action here
                    
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.cartvoltDarkBlue)
            }
           .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Text("Item")
                Spacer()
                Text("Quantity")
                Spacer()
                Text("Price")
                Spacer()
                Text("Store")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(10)
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                var mutableItem = self.items[index]
                                mutableItem.isComplete.toggle()
                                
                                // Find the index of the `item` object in the `items` array
                                for (i, element) in self.items.enumerated() where element.id == mutableItem.id {
                                    self.items[i] = mutableItem
                                }
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: self.items[index].isComplete ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                            }
                            TextField("Enter item name", text: self.$items[index].name, onCommit: {
                                self.addRow()
                            })
                            Divider()
                            
                        }
                        TextField("Enter item quantity", text: self.$items[index].quantity, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                        Divider()
                        TextField("Enter price", text: self.$items[index].price, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                        Divider()
                        TextField("Enter store name", text: self.$items[index].shopName, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addRow() {
        items.append(Item(id: UUID(), name: "", quantity: "", price: "", complete: "", shopName: "", isComplete: false))
    }

}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var quantity: String
    var price: String
    var complete: String
    var shopName: String
    var isComplete: Bool
}
```

Comment: I've worked on something similar but I ended up with a custom solution using UIKit. Let me know if you’re interested.

Answer (score 0):

`.onDelete` and `.swipeActions` only work on `List`, so I suggest to change the ScollView to List.

Also I strongly recommend to use the initializer `ForEach($items) { $item in` instead of indices, it makes your code cleaner and your life easier:

```
            List {
                ForEach($items, id: \.id) { $item in
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Button {
                                item.isComplete.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: item.isComplete ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                            }
                            TextField("Enter item name", text: $item.name, onCommit: {
                                self.addRow()
                            })
                            Divider()
                            
                        }
                        TextField("Enter item quantity", text: $item.quantity, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                        Divider()
                        TextField("Enter price", text: $item.price, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                        Divider()
                        TextField("Enter store name", text: $item.shopName, onCommit: {
                            self.addRow()
                        })
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: I am fully aware of the approach I took. I used indices because I decided to alocate an individual struct to each list item else all rows will have the same data as the last entered row, since they all share a state variable to to update and also display view. Secondly, I don’t want to use a list view because I intend to have 2 buttons in each row and when I do, both get activated. Thanks for the help but I’ve already tried with that